# htaccess redirect on empty directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

My website is built up like the following

www.domain.com/products/catname/myproduct.php

www.domain.com/products/myproduct.php

Some files are in deeper directories. I am wanting to redirect www.domain.com/products/catname/ (for example) to a certain page. My directories do not include index files.

How do I do this using htaccess?

I have tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch permanent ^/products http://domain.co.uk/
RedirectMatch permanent ^/products/productname http://domain.co.uk/
```

But this redirect any file in the /products directory (domain.co.uk/products/prod1.php for example will redirect to domain.co.uk)

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On

RedirectMatch permanent ^/products http://domain.co.uk/

RedirectMatch permanent ^/products/productname http://domain.co.uk/

Comment: This redirect the /products/product.php to the destination which it shouldnt. Only is someone browses to the directory root

Comment: Update your question with that, that way more people can help you.

Comment: I have updated it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_alias:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch permanent ^/products/?(productname)?$ http://domain.co.uk/
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?products/?(productname)?$ http://domain.co.uk/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Works a treat...just one thing..

So I have it redirected to http://tempdomain.com/page.php

I am building the site on a demo server. So I will have to change each redirect link. Unless there is a way to pull the host address??

Comment: @LCDesignCambridge not sure what you mean by having to change each redirect link.

Comment: @LCDesignCambridge Oh wait, do you mean you are redirecting to the same host that you are requesting `/products/` from? If so, then simply remove the `http://domain.co.uk` part, and it will redirect to the same host.

Comment: great ok. If I need to go back a directory or two do I simply use ../ ?

Comment: @LCDesignCambridge `../` isn't guaranteed to work. If you're going to need to redirect to a parent directory, try: `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch permanent ^/products/[^/]+/ http://domain.co.uk/somepage.htm
RedirectMatch permanent ^/products http://domain.co.uk/
```

substitute 'somepage.htm' above for the actual page you want to redirect to.